# Обработка сигнала системы SIGHUP

Tags: windows, golang, syscall

Пробую перехватить сигнал завершения процесса:

```golang
func main() {
    c := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(c, syscall.SIGHUP)
    for s := range c {
        fmt.Println("сигнал", s.String())
        return
    }
}
```

Не работает, в консольке выводится `exit status 1`.

Тот же пример, но с `SIGINT` работает норм.

Comment: Какую OS вы используете? Как отправляете сигнал приложению? Ваш код по debian работает нормально

Comment: я пробовал в windows, завершаю через диспетчер задач

Answer (score 1):

Выдержка из интернет:

> SIGINT - этот сигнал аналогичен нажатию ctrl-c. Процесс прерывается и
>   останавливается. Однако процесс может игнорировать этот сигнал.
>
> SIGHUP - сигнал отключает процесс от родительского процесса. Это также
>   может быть использовано для перезапуска процессов.

Есть предположение, что диспетчер задач посылает SIGINT.

Comment: я оба перехватывал, тоже самое (+ SIGTERM на всякий)